# Golang Facebook response to struct

Tags: go, struct

Hi there I'm new in GO and I'm trying to convert a json from the facebook api to struct.

The problem is that the keys of the object are dinamic:

```
{
  "100555213756790": {
    "id": "100555213756790",
    "about": "Noodle Bar & Restaurant",
    "metadata": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "description": "asdasdasdasd",
          "type": "numeric string"
        },
        //...
  ,
  "101285033290986": {
    "id": "101285033290986",
    "about": "Smart City Expo World Congress",
    "metadata": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "description": "fgddgdfgdg",
          "type": "numeric string"
        },
```

what I have achieved so far is extract the objects by id and turn them into a map:

```
for _, id := range ids {
    fbPages, ok := results[string(id)].(map[string]interface{})
    if ok {
        for k, v := range fbPages {
            fmt.Println(k)
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
}

//json to Page struct?
    type Page struct {
        ID                string   `json:"id"`
        About             string   `json:"about"`
    }

    type Metadata struct {
        Fields      []Field           `json:"fields"`
        Type        string            `json:"type"`
        Connections map[string]string `json:"connections"`
    }

    type Field struct {
        Name        string  `json:"name"`
        Description string  `json:"description"`
        Type        *string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    }
```

My question is:

how can I convert that map to struct? or is there any easy way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting map to struct:

```
import "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"

mapstructure.Decode(myMap, &myStruct)
```

[example](https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#example-Decode)

But I would do this:

```
type Page struct {
    ID                string   `json:"id"`
    About             string   `json:"about"`
    //other fields and nested structs like your metadata struct
}
type fbPages map[string]Page
```

Comment: Do you know why when I decode with mapstructure the struct has empty values?

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor Please refer to this example, https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#example-Decode and check for differences in your code. I can confirm that the example is working, although I prefer second method in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, thank you. Only one question, do you know the integer values are 0?

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor you mean initial integer value? if so Yes, its initialized as 0.

Comment: No sorry, the Page struct has more values like talking_about_count. So before  Decode the value is for example 45 and after Decode is 0 :S

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor I checked with provided example again (link in answer) it has a field named Age and is indeed an integer, and I can see it is indeed is set to 91 when converted into struct.

Comment: Yes I did the same but I give 0, I'll ask to SO if im missing something.
Thank you.

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor no problem mate.